# Why would WooCommerce Product Attributes disappear on save

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a WooCommerce store that has products with attributes that are associated with variations. When I save products, the attributes disappear (and therefore the associated variations do, too). When I re-add the attributes and save the product again, the variations come back as they were. (Note that this means attributes don’t always disappear - only when they’re not manually added before saving. )
No errors are logged.
I'm looking for some insight as to why this would happen.

Comment: when you say `re-add`, you're not saving it? Your descriptions seems confusing.

Comment: Can you please share the screen-shots what is actually happening ?

Comment: Edited to try to clarify. I’ll try to add screenshots a little later today.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue since I use Ozisti theme for my site, too.

The workaround was to do NOT USE "Save attributes" button on product page. To save attributes changes USE "Update" (product page - on the top/right of the page).

The problem has been solved with Ozisti ThemeREX support team. They sent me new files:

wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/components/api/woocommerce/woocommerce-extended-attributes.php 
wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/includes/plugin.wp.php

and now it works fine.

Regards, Jacek

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar problem.
WordPress 5.1.1
WooCommerce 3.5.7
Ozitsi 1.0.2 Theme by ThemeRex (here was the problem)

**Solution summary:** Add attribute, add options, press SAVE ATTRIBUTES (attribute row folds) -> UNFOLD IT immediately - **if you don't see options inserted a second ago into the Comboselect field read on**.

In my case plugin ThemeREX Add-ons (shipped with Ozisti theme) was the issue. It added extra attribute types, so I could turn variations between dropdown select, image, color and button types.

After few hours of debugging I noticed that when attribute was set to one of the new types, UPDATING PRODUCT did erase all added attributes -> and by extension variations.
After ADDING ATTRIBUTES again (without **SAVE ATTRIBUTES** button - just adding attributes and **UPDATING product**) all was back in place.
Notice: when you **SAVE ATTRIBUTES** the row with options closes, the variations become available. But when I opened the attribute row after all AJAX saving was done it turned out that there were no OPTIONS placed in this Wordpress combo select of attribute I just edited.
So on UPDATING PRODUCT WooCommerce saved empty attribute options into DB.

This might not be perfect solution but I solved this by modifying WooCommerce's **meta-boxes-product.js**
I commented out line 465 and added another line to close the row:

```
$( '.product_attributes' ).html( response.data.html );
$( '.product_attributes .woocommerce_attribute.open .handlediv' ).trigger('click');
```

I didn't trace everything to the roots but makinkg it work for this single project is good enough for me at this point.

You probably use other plugins then me, but maybe they do something similar to my case.

**So try** to SAVE ATTRIBUTES and then immediately open attribute row again and check if selected options are inserted.. if not.. try my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This Happen to me This Year. I was debugging my store for 3 days.
Solution:

I load a css file on Wordpress back office with these lines:

```
.save_attributes, .save-variation-changes {
    display:none !important;
}
```

This makes WooCommerce Hide 2 buttons.
Save Attribute and Save Variation. So clients will be forced to use the update button in the product page. I'm still not sure if this is a Woocommerce bug or other plugin but for some reason, if I pressed one of these 2 buttons I would lose all my variations.

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar solution with @Maciej Dejewski using Woocommerce v3.6.5.

On file /plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-product.js or /plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-product.min.js (depends on your admin page calling the javascript - you can check it via inspect element)

But instead adding line

```
$( '.product_attributes .woocommerce_attribute.open .handlediv' ).trigger('click');
```

Just commented out this

```
$( '.product_attributes' ).html( response.data.html );
```

Working fine for me

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkV9Z.png)

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for a hour, it turns out that my variations only disappear when not each attribute is selected. However, some of my product's attributes have between 10 and 150 entries..so that is the downside when using this method.

[image]
[image]